# root directory IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python

I am working on Ubuntu and writing a code in python. I want to add a line in a file which is placed in root directory:

```
ins = open( "/usr/local/etc/conf.d/test.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append( line )
array.append('add this new line')
f = open("/usr/local/etc/gnuradio/test.txt",'w')
for line in array:
   f.write(line)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overwrite.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open("/usr/local/etc/gnuradio/test.txt",'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/gnuradio/test.txt'
```

I know we do not have permission to change anything in root directory without using sudo. But is there anyway I can update this file from within my python module?

Comment: This isn't a Python problem, or even a programming problem; it's a basic question about using Unix-like systems.

Comment: yes you are right but I know that python have some solution to run sudo command like pexpect, so I thought it might have some solution for such problem

Comment: `pexpect` doesn't know anything about `sudo`. Sure, you can write code that uses it to drive `sudo` to run another Python instance on a script that does the actual work… but why? If you really want to leave your password lying around in plain text, there are more fun ways to do it.

Comment: @abarnert I don't know much about Unix-like systems either, but would this work if the script was invoked using sudo?

Comment: @Asad: Yes; one of the two usual ways to do something like this is to run the script under `sudo` (or to run it with the appropriate permissions in some other way—schedule it for root to run later, suexec it, etc.). The other is, of course, to `chmod` the file so your normal user has permission to write it. Hyperboreus's answer covered both of these. Neither one needs any code inside the script.

Answer (score 2):

You already answered your own question: You do not have the permission to do so.

No matter if you use sh, bash, python, C, erlang or a rubber-hose attack.

Either run your script with a user owning the necessary permissions or grant yourself access to the file.